# On $X = C(0,1)$ define $T:X \to X$ by $T(f)(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$ for all $f$ in $X$. Is $T$ invertible$?$

Tags: linear-algebra

On $X = C(0,1)$ define $T:X \to X$ by $T(f)(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ for all $f$ in $X$. 
Is $T$ invertible$?$

Clearly, $T$ is one one (injective) , since only zero functions will be mapped to zero function, $T$ is one one (injective).

How can I check surjectivity $?$

Comment: I'd say $T$ is not well-defined. What's $T(x^{-1})$ supposed to be?

Comment: It seems to me that $T$ is not surjective. Surjectivity here would mean that every function is $X$ has corresponding function integral of which he represents. However any function represented by operator $T$ is necessarily (continuously) differentiable. However not all function in $X$ has to be differentiable.

Comment: So you can take any non-differentiable but continuous function, and can easily state that it can't be represented as an integral of given form.

Comment: Better notation: $T(f)(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$, as $T(f)$ should be in $X$ hence be a function of $x \in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $r(x)=\left|x-\frac 12\right|$, now $r\in X$ ,but not exists a $t(x)\in X,s.t.r=T(t)$